# Getting last week's tweets for a given hashtag

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am facing the challenge to count the number of tweets for a given hashtag from last week of making a query.

I had a look at [Twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) and it offers parameter "until" that limits the response tweets up to the given date and since_id - return tweets starting from a tweet with a given id.... both options do not seem to be ideal in the case where I am looking for tweets of a given hashtag from last week and count them later on.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Do you guys have ideas for solutions?

Best,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to monitor twitter constantly, and use the `until` functionality to prevent duplicate counts.

Store the counts in a database for this.

As far as I know, there is no endpoint to count hashtags.